# Are commensurable subgroups contained in a finite overgroup?

Tags: group-theory, lattices-in-lie-groups

Let $\Gamma$ and $\Lambda$ be commensurable discrete lattices in a semi-simple Lie group $G$, i.e. the intersection $\Gamma\cap\Lambda$ has finite index in both $\Gamma$ and $\Lambda$.  Let $\Omega=\langle\Gamma,\Lambda\rangle$.

When is $[\Omega:\Gamma]$ and $[\Omega:\Lambda]$ finite?  Moreover, can we say anything about either index?

If $\Gamma$ and $\Lambda$ are not arithmetic, then by Margulis they are finite index inside their commensurator.  So I am only interested in the case when $\Gamma$ and $\Lambda$ are arithmetic.

Comment: Your claim "If ... are not arithmetic" is false... maybe you're implicitly assuming that these are lattices and that $G$ is semisimple.

Comment: I am, I'll update the question.  In fact I specifically care about the case $G=PSL_2(\mathbb{R})$ and, $\Gamma$ and $\Lambda$ are Fuchsian groups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me assume that you implicitly mean $G$ to be semisimple and the discrete subgroups to be (arithmetic) lattices.

Here's an example where they are not contained in a finite index overgroup. Namely $G=\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{R})$ (you can do something similar in $G=\mathrm{SL}_d(\mathbf{R})$ for $d\ge 2$), $\Gamma=\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{Z})$, and $\Lambda=g^{-1}\Gamma g$ with $g=\begin{pmatrix}2 & 0\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$. 
Thus $$\Lambda=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}a & b\\ c & d\end{pmatrix}\in\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{Z}[1/2]): a,d\in\mathbf{Z},b\in\frac12\mathbf{Z},c\in2\mathbf{Z}\right\}.$$
Hence $\Omega$ contains the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\ 1/2 & 1\end{pmatrix}$, and hence its transpose as well (using conjugation by some integral matrix) and these generate $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{Z}[1/2])$, so $\Omega=\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{Z}[1/2])$.

Comment: Are there similar examples when $g\in SL_2(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: Yes, there are, take $g'=g^2/2$.

Comment: Perfect thank you!